# set DatePicker field in javafx to empty field?

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker

How to set the datepicker to an empty field?

I have button the user will confirm with the button I want the datepicker to delete whatever the user chose. For example, for the textfield i used the following statement:

```
TextField userName = new TextField();
```

Then I clean it using the following statement:

```
userName.setText("");
```

but I can't do the same thing for the datepicker object since it has not setText function.

And the same thing for the ComboBox object. I dont want it to choose the first one. I want it to reshow the PromptText message. For example,

```
ComboBox items = new ComboBox();
items.setPromptText("Choose From Below");
```

Once the user choose from it, and press the button how to redisplay the prompt message again.

Comment: `setValue(null)` doesn't work?

Comment: cheers, works with both. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComboBoxBase` defines a `valueProperty` that is inherited by both `DatePicker` and `ComboBox` and represents the currently selected item. So you can call

```
datePicker.setValue(null);
```

or

```
// items is the combo box you defined:
items.setValue(null);
```

to clear the value from either one.